# How to continue the scripts after ng build is completed?

Tags: angular, batch-file

I have my own script that allows me to run specific commands. Here is a sample:

1. go to the client folder: `cd client`
2. run ng build: `ng build --prod`
3. go to the server folder: `cd server`
4. run dotnet publish: `dotnet publish -o ../Publish`

The issue is that script stops after ng build (step 2) and doesn't execute the next one. How can I run all the commands as described in the sample? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your package.json's scripts block I would place

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:client": "cd client && ng build --prod",
    "deploy:dotnet": "cd server && dotnet publish -o ../Publish",
    "deploy": "npm run build:client && npm run deploy:dotnet"
  }
}
```

The magic here is `&&` which allows you to chain commands

and using package.json's scripts you can call

```
npm run deploy
```